# Hiding picture of the camera in SparkAR

Tags: spark-ar-studio

for our project we need to hide the picture of the camera in SparkAR Studio. The camera must be turned on, but we don't want to see what the camera is filming, only a black background.
Is there a better way except putting a black object over the picture?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a black object as you suggest using a 2D rectangle that obscures the camera view, or you could use render passes and just disconnect the camera texture.